# Move to fresh database don't take non standard items

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I would like to take standard core data (i.e products, orders, attributes, etc) from my magento 1.9.2.2 store into a fresh 1.9.2.2 database without any of the extra data and fields that have been added by other modules.

has anyone else done this? or have any advice on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Four step process:

1. Delete all other modules from your old Magento 1.9.2.2 **or** disable from global configuration file inside **app/etc/modules**
2. Install one new Magento 1.9.2.2  using different database **(Suppose A)**.
3. Connect your old magento 1.9.2.2 with this new database **A** by making changes in app/etc/local.xml
4. Locate rows **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** in table **core_config_data** database **A** & Change url as your old one.

That's it.

Comment: This doesn't take across products and orders tho?